# Can I create with LaTeX documents in the EPUB-format?

Tags: latex, epub, tex

Is it possible to create a document for an ebook-reader in the EPUB-format with LaTeX/TeX? Which extension or program can be used?

Comment: This is an interesting topic due to the huge amount of scientific publications where LaTeX is used.

Comment: A similar question was later asked on tex.stackexchange.com. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1551/1243.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can [convert LaTeX to XHTML](http://jblevins.org/log/latex/xml-tools) and then [convert XHTML to EPUB](http://www.epubbooks.com/blog/20080925/creating-an-epub-document/).

Comment: If only those Latex to XHTML converters were not 100-step install processes on windows...

Answer (score 10):

Pandoc can do this directly -- http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/   It's a great command-line tool.

pandoc -s example4.tex -o example4.epub

Comment: Pandoc can do this directly, if 9and only if) you have no \import or \include directives in your laTeX (unless something's changed in the last few months that is).

Comment: ...and if there are no cross-references.

Answer (score 5):

As noted by @Alexey Romanov a way is to convert from LaTeX to XHTML then to EPub. The ePub standard does not support MathML, but SVG 1.1 is supported and mathematical equations and graphs should be rendered just fine while preserving searchability and scaling.

http://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/SVG#General_Notes_on_SVG_Usage_in_ePUB

(Please update if you find the ultimate tool-chain to deal with this easily.)

Comment: epub3 now supports MathML: http://idpf.org/epub/30/spec/epub30-contentdocs.html#sec-xhtml-mathml

Answer (score 3):

The answer looks to be Yes, via some converter, but latex probably isn't the best way.

From http://www.web-books.com/Publishing/epub.htm:

> The EPUB format is a standard eBook format recommended by The International Digital Publishing Forum. It is essentially a ZIP format. If you change its extension ".epub" to ".zip", the EPUB file becomes a true ZIP file which can be unzipped.
>
> The unzipped EPUB files may be divided into three categories: XHTML documents, packaging files and container files.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Link on how to covert tex to epub with tex4ebook under windows
https://d800fotos.wordpress.com/2015/01/19/create-e-books-from-latex-tex-files-ebook-aus-latex-tex-dateien-erstellen/

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.